# Tests with CUNIT - walkthrough analysis / code coverage

Tags: c, testing, code-coverage, cunit

I want to test some code with CUnit. Does anyone know if it is possible to do a walktrough Analysis?

I want to have something, that says, you`ve tested 80% of your function.

It must be ensured, that 100% coverage are reached with the test.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tools that will help - the basic free one is [gcov](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html), which will do what you need but will involve a certain amount of setup, etc.

There are other (commercial) ones, but what's available changes, including if there are non-commercial free/low-cost licences.  Having said that, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeCoverageTools might be worth a starting point if you need more than gcov.

Comment: Yes, thanks. gcov works fine. I added gcovr (python script) to make the code coverage visible.